# The format puzzle

Tags: python, file, format

```
f = open('file.txt')
print f.read()
```

That was pretty straight forward wasn't it? That works because python knows how to read and write`.txt` files. How do these formats even work? I wish to build a python program to read atleast the major formats of documents (including pdfs), spreadsheets and presentations.

Now please don't tell me, "Go ahead and use PDFMiner!"; "Use IronPython for reading `.doc`!".

I want to understand myself, how the format magic happens. I want to know how formats work, so that I Can build my own "any format reader". I dont want solutions to read various formats. I want to know the theory behind it.

Any links to such resources, or help regarding reading multiple formats is greatly appreciated.

-Thank you

Comment: Go ahead and read the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html); and implement your own parser.

Answer (score 7):

No, you have completely misunderstood what your code is doing. Python doesn't "know" how to read .txt files, because there is no "format" here. It is just opening a plain file and printing out the bytes it finds there.

Something like PDF or DOC is completely different. The bytes by themselves do not mean anything: they are the representation of a file format that is understood by the relevant application. In order to "read" them in a way that understands what they contain, you need to build a parser that does the same thing as the original application. That's what those libraries you refer to do (although IronPython is an implementation of Python in .NET, and has nothing to do with reading doc files).

Comment: "The bytes by themselves do not mean anything" -> I'd say that for plain text files the bytes don't mean anything, whereas in the other formats the bytes do have specific meanings.

Comment: `In fact in the case of PDF, the bytes actually represent a PostScript program that constructs the document.` -- I'm not so sure about the second part of this line.

Comment: @devnull it's a bit simplified, but basically right: as [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#PostScript) says, the PDF format is a tokenized version of the original PS.

Comment: i've never stated that there is no format in .txt files

Comment: @DanielRoseman _Basically right_ or not, I wouldn't make that statement.  It's grossly misleading.

Comment: @devnull fair enough, I've removed it.

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi: but there isn't.

Comment: @ErikAllik: MarkDown is a format. The choice of newline convention is a format. The codec used is a format. Etc.

Comment: MarkDown is not Plain Text either (and usually stored as `.md`), even though it's human readable and authorable as plain text; agreed about the other points though.

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely no magic involved in reading a `.txt` file—it's just ASCII bytes, and opening and reading a file does just that: reads bytes. It's the simplest possible file format you could ever find (because there is no format). PDF is to plain Plain Text what Coca Cola is to distilled water.

PDFs however have a very complex format that they use; reading a PDF file would just make Python treat it as if it were as `.txt` file.

So I'm sorry to give you that old response you don't like hearing: please go ahead and use PDFMiner, or read its source code to understand how they're reading and parsing PDF files :) (or read the [PDF spec](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) as devnull pointed out)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to look up the specification for each format you want to deal with, [this](http://www.idpf.org/epub/301/spec/epub-overview.html) is the specification for ePub for example, it's a bit broad but you get the idea, then you need figure out yourself how you want to deal with it.